# CLR Profiler with WCF doesn't work for specific service

Tags: .net, wcf, service, clr, profiler

I need to profile a WCF service, but I get the message "Waiting for service to start common language runtime", it only occurs with this particular service; when I tried with other WCF services, it works fine. I was wondering if I should configure something in the wcf to allow the profile. Both services run with the same account(admin) and the .net framework version of both service is 3.5. Perhaps, I should set something in the config file? I don't know why only in this service the clr profiler doesn't work. The operating system is windows 2003 server.

I'll really appreciate every answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the services as .exes and profile them there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you mean that i create other app? for example an windows app and that it consume the wcf?? And then profile the windows app?.

Comment: No I mean run the services as windows apps and then profile them

Answer (score 0):

The profiler should not really interfere with the service and no matter what you put in the config file, the profiler should work. 
 Since the profiler hooks just about every method call in the CLR, you might see various sorts of concurrency issues that you would not normally see during standard execution; so does your service utilize threading or is it doing something special during startup?

Of course the CLR profiler might also have some bugs in it, so trying with another profiler might also get you what you want - there are several free options out there.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The service use configuration Services, perhaps it generates the issue, but i can not change this in the services, As you suggest think that going to use other profile tool. Thanks.